# native Javascript wait for form fully submitted

Tags: javascript

I have a form with checkboxes. These checkboxes can be chekced/unchecked/required/disabled/enabled. Since unchecked/disabled checkboxes don't get POSTed, every checkbox has a second hidden one. Like this:

```
<div>
    <label class="label"><input type="checkbox" name="testname" value="yes" checked="true" disabled="true">test</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="test" name="testname" value="-" disabled="true">
</div>
```

So whenever a checkbox is unchecked or disabled onsubmit I activate the hidden checkboxes. So my thoughts behind this is:

1. enable hidden checkboes
2. send form
3. put form elements in the same state then before form submit

My Javascript:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('#btnsubmit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach((input) => {
            if (!input.checked){
                console.log(document.getElementById(input.name + "hidden"));
                console.log("ENABLE HIDDEN - input not checked - #" + input.getAttribute('state-before') + "#");
                
                input.setAttribute("state-before", "hidden");
                document.getElementById(input.name + "hidden").disabled = false;
            } else {
                if (input.disabled){
                    console.log(input);
                    console.log("INPUT DISABLED - input disabled - #" + input.getAttribute('state-before') + "#");
                    
                    input.setAttribute("state-before", "disabled");
                    input.disabled = false;
                }
            }
            console.log("-----------");
        });

        document.querySelector('#feuform').submit();
        afterSubmit();
    });

    function afterSubmit(){
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach((input) => {
            console.log("INPUT reset #" + input.getAttribute('state-before') + "#");
            if (input.getAttribute('state-before') === "hidden"){
                document.getElementById(input.name + "hidden").disabled = true;
                console.log(document.getElementById(input.name + "hidden"));
            } else if (input.getAttribute('state-before') === "disabled"){
                input.disabled = true;
                console.log(input);
            }
            console.log("++++++++++");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, my go on it doesn't work like I want it to. Even if I use callback instead the way I do. I tried using a sleep(5s) function which I used before my function `afterSubmit`. When I do the behaviour is exactly the way I expect it to be.

We're working on slow webservers, sleep(2s) seems to be not enough, so I assume that the form-POSTing is so slow, that my issue even exists.

Anyone any idea how to wait till the form is fully submitted with native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect candidate for AJAX

Also never use a button click event on a form. Use the form submit event and preventDefault if needed –

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById("form1")
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const checks = [...document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [type=checkbox]")].reduce((acc, chk) => {
      acc[chk.name] = chk.checked ? chk.value : "N/A";
      return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log("submitting", checks)

    fetch('https://yourserver.com/post', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(checks)
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        form.reset(); // uncheck all or use res to set the checkboxes
      });

  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<label class="label"><input type="checkbox" name="testname1" value="yes" checked>test1</label>
<label class="label"><input type="checkbox" name="testname2" value="yes" checked>test2</label>
<label class="label"><input type="checkbox" name="testname3" value="yes" >test3</label>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Gonna try this out. Commenting back as soon as I tried.

Comment: Your server needs to handle the format they come in. That is very easy to add - just look for JSON and your server language